# Use column set for ALL_SPARSE_COLUMNS in the Sql View

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I add sparse columns dynamically:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table](
    [id] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [column_set] XML COLUMN_SET FOR ALL_SPARSE_COLUMNS)
```

I add sparse columns at runtime with the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_sparse_column ... SPARSE
```

I want to create the SQL view for this table:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_my_view]  
AS  
SELECT v.*       
  FROM my_table v
```

However I cannot query data from my sparse columns when I use the view:

```
SELECT my_sparse_column FROM v_my_view
```

However, I receive such an error:
[image]

This query works fine when executing it on the original table.

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: I think that might be a typo, I didn't see `my_sparse_column` exists in your table  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=4d6d7f01460525350384ebcd45128df8

Comment: This is how `SELECT *` works on column sets. Sticking that query in a view doesn't change the semantics. A view on a table with a column set can only select specific columns (or pass through the column set column) but can't be sparse itself.

Comment: @D-Shih we are adding sparse columns dynamically at runtime to this table

Comment: Are you running `ALTER TABLE ... ADD ...`? If so you also need to run `sp_refreshview` on the view

Comment: Since there are already two people who don't understand what you're doing (which is understandable, as column sets aren't exactly a commonly used feature), I recommend [edit]ing the question to include the `ALTER TABLE ... ADD my_sparse_column ... SPARSE` statement. Something [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b45cb647b80265475bbf306b4fced002).

Comment: As for ways to make it work, I'd say either don't use a view, or alter it dynamically whenever you add a sparse column -- using `SELECT *` in views is a bad pattern anyway. Generating the `SELECT` statement to mention all the columns can be a little annoying, but it's doable (even in T-SQL from a DDL trigger, if absolutely necessary, though doing it client-side is much more convenient).

Comment: If you literally just need a different name for the table (that is, you don't have to apply security or further filtering in the view) a synonym should also work (disclaimer: not tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This behaviour is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-column-sets?view=sql-server-ver16#guidelines-for-selecting-data-from-a-column-set) for `SPARSE` columns when there is a `COLUMN_SET` present.**

> **Warning:**
>
> Adding a column set changes the behavior of `SELECT *` queries. The query will return the column set as an XML column and **not return** the individual sparse columns. Schema designers and software developers must be careful not to break existing applications. **Individual sparse columns can still be queried by name in a `SELECT` statement.**

So the view will never contain that column, unless you specifically select it, not just using `select *`.

---

There is another issue that you would get even if it wasn't `SPARSE`.

You are adding the column *after* creating the view.

You need to then run the following statement:

```sql
EXEC sp_refreshview N'dbo.v_my_view';
```

When creating a view, the view is parsed into a compiled expression tree (without any optimizations). Then, when you use the view, the compiler does not simply dump the view text into the outer query. Instead, it parses the outer query into an expression tree, and uses the expression tree from the view in the correct place.

So when you add a column, the expression tree is not updated. So you need to refresh the view definition.

---

You also need to rebuild any stored procedures which access this table or the view, for the same reason.

```sql
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule N'dbo.YourProc';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6786bab891b131f403e35e89442b1d98)

Comment: `sp_refreshview` has no effect on the semantics of `SELECT * FROM my_table` in this case. It executes the exact same way both before and after adding the sparse column (that is, by returning the column set column and not any sparse columns). The newly added sparse column doesn't become part of the view's structure and the optimizer doesn't see through the XML field as a column set. The latter behavior is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-column-sets#guidelines-for-using-column-sets).

Comment: The problem lies specifically in the use of a column set. For sparse columns in general your answer would apply, but for this case it does not. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6786bab891b131f403e35e89442b1d98).

Comment: Thanks, have modified